# I am trying to make a table. It does not give output. no error

Tags: tables

```
\begin{center}


\begin{tabular}{ c c c c c c c c c }


  &  & Line Winding & Valve Windiing & Valve Windiing \\ 

 Rated Voltage &  &  & Star & Delta \\  
  Rated voltage at tap \ddag 0, phase to earth & {$kV_{rms}$} & {$525/\sqrt3$} & {$210.4/\sqrt3$} & 210.4\\
Rated power {$(S_{N2w})$} & MVA & 297.5 & 297.5 & 297.5\\ 
Current ratings, bipolar operation &  &  &  &\\
 Rated continuous current, without redundant & {$A_{rms}$} & 982 & 2449 & {$2449/\sqrt3$}\\
cooling in service, at nominal tap &  &  &  & \\
Line winding tap changer regulating range &  &  &  &  \\
Number of steps &  & +25/-5 &  &  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Adding `\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` to your code, I get (ugly) output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rn4dd.png. Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: You can replace `{ c c c c c c c c c}` with `{ *{9}c}` but consider the format of the table, it's ugly, as @samcarter already noticed

Comment: And [welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) - please don't take the "ugly" personally - not you, just your table :)

Comment: Which program to you run to compile your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your table look better, I suggest you change the code along the lines showing in the following example. It should compile equally well under pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, and XeLaTeX.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry,booktabs,siunitx,amsmath,ragged2e,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}} % automatic inline math mode
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\hangafter=1\hangindent=1em}X}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} YlCCC @{}}
Rated Voltage & 
& {\text{Line Winding}} & {\text{Valve Winding}} & {\text{Valve Winding}} \\ 
& & & {\text{Star}} & {\text{Delta}} \\  
\midrule
Rated voltage at tap $\ddag0$, phase to earth 
& $\si{\kilo\volt}_{\mathrm{rms}}$ & 525/\sqrt3 & 210.4/\sqrt3 & 210.4\\
Rated power $(S_{N2w})$ 
& \si{\mega\watt} & 297.5 & 297.5 & 297.5\\ 
\addlinespace
Current ratings, bipolar operation\\
Rated continuous current, without redundant cooling in service, at nominal tap  
& $\si{\ampere}_{\mathrm{rms}}$ & 982 & 2449 & 2449/\sqrt3\\ 
\addlinespace
Line winding tap changer regulating range \\
Number of steps &  & +25/{-}5 &  &  \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: this works. (y) very informative